# css height:100% for childs made over flow abnormally

Tags: css

hi i would like to make full height for a left and side bars i must be 100% height but it made a little buggy my css looks like

```
 html{
  height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
   }

body{
 height: 100%;
 }

.container{
   background-color: #999;
    padding: 20px;
    height:100%;
  }

.sidebar{
   background-color: #9999ff;
   float:left;
   width:30%;
   height:100%;
 }

.content{
   background-color: #99ff99;
   float:left;
   width:70%;
   height:100%
   }
```

this is my fiddle

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vivekranth/CTdyw/)

if i did height:100% for childs means most of the contents are get overflowed.

Answer (score 0):

display **.container** as table:

```
.container{
    background-color: #999;
    padding: 20px;
    display:table;
    height:100%;
}

.sidebar{
    background-color: #9999ff;
    display:table-cell;
    width:30%;
 }

.content{
    background-color: #99ff99;
    display:table-cell;
    width:70%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/56C9v/15/

Answer (score 0):

i've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56C9v/14/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

html{
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

```
body{
    height: 100%;
}

.container{
    background-color: #999;
    padding: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar{
    background-color: #9999ff;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.content{
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #99ff99;
    float:right;
}
```